# Shirk thoughts doubts that I act upon them

Tags: sin, shirk, forgiveness, doubts

I watched a video where I wanted to feel better of ocd shirk thought and the person said who are these whispers from and he said Shaitan I nodded my head yes and I was afraid that I just acted upon it please help I just don’t want to commit shirk and avoid major sins and just do minors sin not major did I commit shirk?

Comment: Why are you so worried about this?

Comment: I don’t know it’s hard to control

Comment: Ok don't try to control it, let it be happen, let those thoughts come to your mind, as long as you hate those thoughts you are not doing any shirk and you are not sinful for this